# Does the Identity Server require the database to be high availability?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are working on setting up the wso2 production environment and the question came up about the importance of having high availability databases on the identity server side. We have concerns regarding access tokens. Does the IDS manage all that information or is it shared among the other DBs? Also, if the DB happens to go down on the IDS side, will it case all of wso2 to crash? Will APIs no longer be available for use? I can't seem to find much documentation on the matter.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database high availability is needed for WSO2 products.Tokens will be saved in the database. If database goes down, Identity server will not function properly.